# Class cast error with ComboBox when reading a Grid

Tags: grid, vaadin-grid

Getting this error when trying to read the grid.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid cannot be cast to class
> com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox
> (com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid and
> com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox are in unnamed module of
> loader 'app')

```java
private boolean fieldValidation() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getComponentCount() - 1; i++) {
        ComboBox<String> cb = (ComboBox<String>) getComponentAt(i);
        String value = cb.getValue();
        int S_No = 0;
        Form_Output c2 = new Form_Output(S_No, Activity, Paperless, Presenceless, Cashless);
        if (value == null) {
            Notification.show("Please select at one of the  3options");
            return false;
        } else {
            List1.add(c2);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `getComponentAt(i)` obviously does _not_ return what you are expecting. You may want to investigate in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is obvious. You have many components in your layout, and they are of different type. Based on exception one of them is a `Grid`, and that naturally cannot be cast to `ComboBox`. Un such case you need to first check if the component is instance of `ComboBox` before casting.

```
   Component component = getComponentAt(i);
       if (component instanceof ComboBox) {
            ComboBox<String> cb = (ComboBox<String>) component;
            String value = cb.getValue();
            int S_No = 0;
            Form_Output c2 = new Form_Output(S_No, Activity, Paperless, Presenceless, Cashless);
            if (value == null) {
                Notification.show("Please select at one of the  3options");
                return false;
            } else {
                List1.add(c2);
            }
       }
```